# Using CSS attr() function to rotate an element

Tags: css, attr

How do I rotate an element by its *data-rotate* attribute using [attr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr) ?
something like:

```
transform: rotate(attr(data-rotate deg))
```

Comment: See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr) for  comprehensive information and current browser compatiblity. I'd recommend using JavaScript for now, until browsers fully support the `attr()` expression.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation `attr` is experimental for properties other than content.